# How can I grep date in complex pattern?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have line like this:

```
...XXX_YYY_ZZZ_201504072235_AAA...
```

I can use grep for date like this:

```
grep -oP '(?<!\d)201\d{9}'
```

But I have line like this and I can't use grep because of _ character:

```
...XXX_YYY_ZZZ_20150407_2235_AAA...
```

I can use grep for `yearmonthday`

```
grep -oP '(?<!\d)201\d{5}'
```

How can I use grep for `yearmonthdayhourminute`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
grep -oP '(?<!\d)201\d{5}_\d{4}'
```

of if you have both patterns at the same time:

```
grep -oP '(?<!\d)201(\d{9}|\d{5}_\d{4})'
```

Comment: Yes, it's work for me. And I use `tr -d '_'` for remove _ character.